# Reactjs, this.context is deprecated

Tags: reactjs

After switching to new Context API in React introduced in 16.3.0, this.context is being shown as deprecated even though the official docs tells you to use it like this:

```
 class MyClass extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* perform a side-effect at mount using the value of MyContext */
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* ... */
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* ... */
  }
  render() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* render something based on the value of MyContext */
  }
}
MyClass.contextType = MyContext;
```

Comment: Are both react and react-dom at the same version 16.6.3

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, I have both of them at 16.6.3. That is why I was confused that this.context was being shown deprecated.

Comment: Can you create a Codesandbox reproducing your problem. It might also so happen that the libraries that you are using aren't supporting the latest context and also you might have used context the old way somewhere else too

Comment: Also have the same issue

Answer (score 4):

Using context API like you have used in your case is Supported before version 16.3.0 and post 16.6.0.

The API changed a bit between 16.3.0 to 16.6.0 where you need to use a Consumer render prop pattern but was later refined to support the contextType pattern to allow usage of Context in lifecycle method

If you are using the API like you mentioned above, please make sure that you are using a version of React above 16.6.0

If you are using version betwee 16.3.0 to 16.6.0, use Context like

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let value = this.props.context;
    /* perform a side-effect at mount using the value of MyContext */
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    let value = this.props.context;
    /* ... */
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    let value = this.props.context;
    /* ... */
  }
  render() {
    let value = this.props.context;
    /* render something based on the value of MyContext */
  }
}

export default (props) => (
   <MyContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => <MyClass {...props} context={context}/>}
   </MyContext.Consumer>
)
```

Comment: Yes, I am using React 16.6.3.

Comment: I am using React 16.10.2 still I am getting this deprecation warning.

Answer (score 0):

Or use functional wrapper with hook `useContext`:

```
export const withMyContext = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const myContext = useContext(MyContext)
  return <WrappedComponent myContext={myContext} {...props} />
}
```